# Laravel Blade Template - Put php built-function or maybe laravel helper inside yield

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

do you ever use PHP built-in function inside `blade yield` ?
For example can we do something like this :

```
// master layouts
@yield(ucwords('title'))

// view
@section('title', $title)
```

Note: `$title` is from controller

I've already try the first example, but it doesn't work. It doesn't output the `$title` on my view. Right now I am using this in all of my views

```
// master layouts
@yield('title')

// view 1
@section('title', ucwords($title))

// view 2
@section('title', ucwords($title))

// view 3
@section('title', ucwords($title))
```

But I think on second example, I'm not DRY my code because I always repeating the `ucwords()` on each my view. Can we using it on master layout right on yield declaration?

Thank you guys, have a nice work!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own blade directive for example if you want to make a @ucfirst() then do something like this in `AppServiceProvider` .

```
Blade::directive('ucfirst', function ($expression) {
return ucfirst($expression);
```

});

Past this into `boot()`

or on each `section()` you can extend the main layout `@section('title', ucwords($title))` or make the helpers like i mentioned above

as you mentioned above you can use `yield()`

```
        @yield('title',ucwords(strtolower('Your title')))
```

Comment: If we make a helper on `AppServiceProvider`, how can we use the `@ucfirst()` on master layout?

Comment: as we call normal blade helpers with @

Comment: and if you want to share data with all your views then you can use viewcomposer and through this pass it to your master.blade.php or make a @yield() fro titles